# Accessing an API directly through client side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, curl

I think I am being stupid here but can you access the following API directly in JavaScript? - https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/

It only gives examples for using cURL and I guess that would be making AJAX requests to a PHP file or something?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that it allows authenticated GET requests.  jQuery's `get` _may_ allow you to perform the same requests: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: hey thanks, if thats documented could you point me to it?